# Get active Visual Studio object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte

using this code I get the object representing Visual Studio:

```
var dte2 = Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0") as DTE2;
```

However, when I have multiple instances of VS opened, this returns any instance of VS, not the one I am currently executing the code from.

I am not within an add-in so I don't have access to the applicationObject.

How can I get the current Visual Studio instance??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pulling the Active Window Handle (Foreground Window) with the Windows API's.

Comment: then you just cast that handle to a DTE2? how would you make the leap from having the window handle?